# Save password in CheckPoint VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop

For remote work I use CheckPoint SecuRemote, and upon connect, it asks me for password; how can I cache this password?

- Are these settings related to my question?

  ```ini
  # Within: %ProgramFiles(x86)/CheckPoint/Endpoint Connect/trac.defaults
    neo_remember_user_password            STRING  false   GW_USER 0
    neo_remember_user_password_timeout    INT     1440    GW_USER 0
  ```

Answer (score 0):

[Checkpoint document](http://dl3.checkpoint.com/paid/16/sr95cache.pdf?HashKey=1492532341_40d96bb0b90555c302c0e7fd13301d98&xtn=.pdf) specify the following for Win95/98:

> Caching SecuRemote credentials on Win95/98 Desktops:
>
> 1. Kill SecuRemote from the active toolbar
> 2. Remove the SecuRemote auto start key from the Registry:
>
>    ```powershell
>    # Delete key: C:\Program Files\CheckPoint\SecuRemote\bin\fwenc.exe
>      HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\run
>    ```
> 3. In the Windows Startup group, create the following shortcut where you add the `–n` and `–p`  options to cache the user credentials for `SecuRemote`, which must be a static scheme like `Firewall -1 password`
>
>    ```powershell
>    # Full path name must be in quotes if the path contains spaces:
>
>    # Default path for `SecuRemote` is:
>      C:\program files\checkpoint\securemote\bin\fwenc.exe
>    ```
>
>    - `Username`, `password`, and `certificate-full-name` may not contain spaces:
>
>      ```powershell
>      fwenc.exe -n username -p password
>      fwenc.exe -c certificate-full-name -p password
>      ```

Comment: My 64-bit installation of CheckPoint (from `E80.64_CheckPointVPN.msi`) have no `fwenc.exe` executable. I believe that information for Win98 is outdated.